# Live share for Visual Studio Code get stuck after signing in

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

[image]

After I sign in with Microsoft or Github and it shows:

> "You are signed in now and can close this page."

The window saying:

> "Starting collaboration session: Signing In"

in VScode is still there and nothing seemed to happen, how do I fix this??

Answer (score 2):

hope this message finds you well, actually i recently had this same issue whenever i selected live share, on the bottom right corner pop up a message sayng like "Starting collaboration session: Signing In" and it freezes there... if you take a look on the top middle on your screen, in the search bar in vscode you will see another pop up asking you if you would like to sign in with github, select that option and check the permissions after those steps you should not have any other drawback, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this via WSL, you may have networking issues. There are 2 distinct ones: MTU and nameservers.

I had issue with MTU. Long story short, try this command inside your terminal
sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1350

Otherwise, check these answers:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4698#issuecomment-814259640
and if that doesnt help there's this:
https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter/608cfe02319ce60facd76373249b8ca6